# Jemeter: HTTP request, Received successful response header but see "Error: The filter query is missing a value for key 'name'." in the body

Tags: performance, https, jmeter, tableau-api

Jemeter:HTTP request for tableau URL, Received successful response header but see "Error: The filter query is missing a value for key 'name'." in the body

Header data shows 200 OK and bytes data but response body do not have any info other than the message.

I do not understand this error message. I am just passing a direct tableau home link specific to my organization.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your script is not sending some data needed by the service that you are hitting.  Look carefully at what you are sending using the debug sampler.  Compare that to what's needed by your service you described as "direct tableau home link specific to my organization".

To find out whats needed by your service, you may need to record the activity with JMeter proxy recorder or manually inspect the data with other tools such as browser dev tool, wireshark, fiddler, charles, etc